# How can i clean a local Collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor, local, offline

Normally you can only delete single records from a local `Meteor.Collection`.

Comment: Just a bit of friendly advice, SO is a Q&A format website. Can you write an example question/use case in the Question post and follow up with an Answer post? You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
var clean = function(collection) {

    if(collection) {

        // clean items
        _.each(collection.find().fetch(), function(item){
            collection.remove({_id: item._id});
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The cursor returned from `Collection.find` has a `forEach` method, which would be more suitable to use than first fetching the result as an array and then using `_.each`.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: This code is untested, but hopefully working: `collection.find().forEach(function(doc){ collection.remove({_id: doc._id}) })`.