# Clear local Meteor Mongo collection on user logout

Tags: meteor, client, minimongo

I am starting to heavily use local minimongo collection

```
LocalItems = new Meteor.Collection null

SomeOtherItems = new Meteor.Collection null
```

and i'd like to be able to empty all of these local collections when a user logs out;
any suggestions?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072350/how-can-i-clean-a-local-collection-in-meteor).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I assume from your code that you're using coffeescript. If not, let me know and I will rewrite it as javascript:

```coffee
Meteor.logout ->
  LocalItems.remove {}
  SomeOtherItems.remove {}
```

If you're using accounts-ui and don't call the `logout` function directly, I think you'll need to do something like this:

```coffee
Deps.autorun ->
  unless Meteor.user()
    LocalItems.remove {}
    SomeOtherItems.remove {}
```

Or you could do this:

```coffee
Template.loginButtons.events
  "click #login-buttons-logout": ->
    LocalItems.remove {}
    SomeOtherItems.remove {}
```

Comment: You get this error: Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]

Comment: You wouldn't want to actually remove them from the collection, just the local copy.